# WSDL for overloaded elements in legacy service

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I am trying to write a [WSDL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) definition for a legacy service whose documentation specifies XML schema that overload root (and other) elements with different definitions for different messages.

A trivial example involves the following schema for one message:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:example:namespace">
    <element name="message" type="boolean"/>
</schema>
```

and the following for another:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:example:namespace">
    <element name="message" type="date"/>
</schema>
```

One cannot therefore directly import each message's schema as given into the WSDL, as it introduces ambiguity over the definition of `{urn:example:namespace}message`.

Nor can one rewrite the schema so that such overloaded elements validate both message types, as this would wrongly imply that either type is valid for either message:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:example:namespace">
    <element name="message">
        <simpleType>
            <union memberTypes="boolean date"/>
        </simpleType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

It strikes me that each message *should* be defined within its own namespace, or else use unambiguous element names within the same namespace.  However, such changes would break the legacy service contract and are therefore sadly not an option.

Grateful for your thoughts and suggestions on how, if at all, one can resolve this dilemma!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Richard Schneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/431359/richard-schneider)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045139/wsdl-for-overloaded-elements-in-legacy-service/6045341#6045341) prompted me to realise that I can overcome the original question in the following way:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:example:namespace">
    <complexType name="booleanMessageType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <element name="message" type="boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="dateMessageType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <element name="message" type="date"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

and then the WSDL:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:ns="urn:example:namespace"
  targetNamespace="urn:example:wsdl">
    <import namespace="urn:example:namespace" location="schema.xsd"/>
    <message name="BooleanMessage">
        <part name="body" type="ns:booleanMessageType"/>
    </message>
    <message name="DateMessage">
        <part name="body" type="ns:dateMessageType"/>
    </message>
    <!-- remainder of WSDL omitted for brevity -->
</definitions>
```

This gave rise to a secondary question, which I will link as a comment to this answer once posted.

Comment: This style is not WS-I BP 1.1 compliant. You must use the `element` attribute, not the `type` attribute on your message parts to be compliant. Also, BTW, this style will often not work because it is ambiguous which namespace the parameter will be in.

Comment: @John Saunders: If no better solution is forthcoming, we can tolerate lack of WS-I BP 1.1 compliance; not sure why the parameter's namespace is ambiguous—would it not be the `targetNamespace` of the WSDL definition (i.e. `urn:example:wsdl`)?

Comment: [The follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046477/referring-to-overloaded-elements-from-different-schema) to which I refer.

Comment: @eggyal: the problem is that the spec was ambiguous. Is it in the targetNamespace? Is it in the namespace of the type? The problem is that different platforms interpreted that differently, leading to a lack of interoperability. `element` is unambiguous - it will always be the namespace of the element.

Comment: @John Saunders: Thanks for explaining, but I'm struggling to keep up!  Is the 'parameter' with the ambiguous namespace the **`body`** `part` of the two `message`s?  What style should be used instead?

Comment: @egg: yes, that's what's ambiguous. One should use `<part name="body" element="ns:dateMessage"/>` instead.

Comment: @John Saunders:  I'm now awfully confused!  If it's ambiguous what namespace **`body`** is created in when using the `type` attribute, why does it become clear when using the `element` attribute?

Comment: @John Saunders: Also, having checked the [WS-I BP 1.1](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html) specification, I think the `type` attribute (far from being non-conformant) is allowed.  Indeed, §[4.4.1](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html#Bindings_and_Parts) states _When a `wsdl:part` element is defined using the `type` attribute, the serialization of that part in a message is equivalent to an implicit (XML Schema) qualification of a `minOccurs` attribute with the value "1", a `maxOccurs` attribute with the value "1" and a `nillable` attribute with the value "false"._

Comment: @eggyal: because the element is in an explicit namespace (from the schema).

Comment: @eggyal: I'll have to review that again, later. I'll try to figure out where I found it was not permitted.

Comment: @John Saunders:  Forgive me, but surely the `complexType` is equally in an explicit namespace (from the schema)?  Indeed, references to the type must be namespace qualified (as they have been in the example above).

Comment: @eggyal: the question is the namespace for the elements in the messages. The fact that an element is of a type which is in a namespace has nothing to do with the namespace of the element itself.

Comment: @John Saunders: Ah, I think I understand what you're getting at.  But any "elements in the message" must be specified under the `complexType`—in this example, they unambiguously exist in the `targetNamespace` of the schema (i.e. `urn:example:namespace`).  Surely in this sense it's no different to `<wsdl:part name="body" element="ns:another"/>` where the schema defines `<xs:element name="another" type="ns:booleanMessageType"/>`: in both cases the namespace of the `message` element within the service message is unambiguous.

Comment: @egg: the elements under the `body` element can be in a different namespace from the `body` element.

Comment: @John Saunders:  Quite.  And they are in this case.  `body` is in the `targetNamespace` of the WSDL (it's not an element in the message); whereas the elements "beneath" it, which are in the message, are in the `targetNamespace` of their respective schema.  I feel that I must be overlooking something critical and obvious!  Indeed, I can't see how this is any different whether one uses the `element` or `type` attribute.

Comment: @egg: consider the case where the targetnamespace of the WSDL is "x" and the type of the part is in "y". What's ambiguous is whether it should be `<x:body><y:child/></x:body>` or '<y:body><y:child/></y:body>`. With element, there is only "y" to consider, so it must always be the latter - unambiguous.

Comment: @John Saunders: I'm now even more confused, as `<body>` elements should not be appearing in the message!  I thought that `name="body"` merely defines a handle by which one can reference the message `part` from elsewhere in the WSDL?

Comment: @egg: let's assume I've misspoken until I get a chance to look at this in detail after work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should not be using a global element named 'message'.  If 'message' is inside of anoither element then you could use something like this:

```
<xs:element name="m1">
   <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="message" type="data"/>
        </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

<xs:element name="m2">
   <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="message" type="boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify that the specified elements form the root of the messages.

Comment: Well I don't have any other ideas.  Good luck.

Comment: Although this has made me think that perhaps I can explicitly reference each such message element using XPath?  Is it possible to do something like `<wsdl:message name="booleanMsg"><wsdl:part element="ns:m1/message"/></wsdl:message>`?

Comment: Or, another thought, perhaps the `xs:id` attribute can help?